# How can I make this regular expression work in Java to grab filename out of Linux 'ls -lrt' output?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to do this in Java:

```
    String patternStr = "\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+(.*)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
```

Example 'ls -lrt' output:

```
drwxrwxr-x    2 bhannan  bhannan      4096 Jun  2 11:27 HelloWorld.xml
```

But it is not picking up the filename from the first group. However, this same regular expression works on regex101.com:

https://regex101.com/r/mR4rH1/2

What am I doing wrong in Java?

And actually if I could get this to work that would be even better:

https://regex101.com/r/mR4rH1/1

Comment: are you trying to get file information in java? there's FAR better ways of doing that than executing the externa `ls` and parsing the output...

Comment: i think its working **[fine](http://ideone.com/DXmxGZ)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest doing this in Java:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("^.*\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\s+", "");
```

where `str` represents each line of `ls -la` output.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mR4rH1/3)

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint ... don't do this. Don't write up such an really really ugly regular expression that doesn't resemble to anything that a human being is able to read and understand. I am pretty sure: the next time you open up this file in your IDE in order to make a subtle change to the regular expression, you will find yourself spending another significant amount of time to get it working.

Meaning: why this way? Why doing a "ls -a"; to then make your regex  ignore most of that output? Wouldn't it make more sense to instruct ls to exactly print that one information you are looking for instead?

Comment: While not going too far into this ... I have no choice. I'm using JSch library and it does ls() which does underlying ls command via SSH. If the server has an alias on ls to something like ls -a I get wrong output. I'm doing a bug work around for the JSch library ... so unfortunately I need to do this.

Comment: Poor you then. As you just explained, that you got one huge problem: if your application is talking to different servers, that might have different configurations - how can you be ever sure that the ls-output coming back will match your regex?

Comment: There is no guarantee but as it stands now if they have the alias setup it will not return a valid filename. There is a much greater chance that I will now be able to pick up the file using this hackery.

Comment: Would it be simpler to use `com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp` to scan and enumerate files?

Comment: I am! And that's the issue I'm having because it calls ls but the alias on the server maps it to ls -lrt instead so it returns the filename and longFilename as something like 'drwxrwxr-x    2 bhannan  bhannan      4096 Jun  2 11:27 HelloWorld.xml' instead of just HelloWorld.xml.

Comment: How sad. Having to build strange workarounds because the server is misconfigured ...

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "drwxrwxr-x    2 bhannan  bhannan      4096 Jun  2 11:27 HelloWorld.xml";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*\\s+(\\S+)","$1"));
}
```

O/P :

```
HelloWorld.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW the initial regexp works for me. Do you sure you use Pattern/Matcher properly?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("drwxrwxr-x    2 bhannan  bhannan      4096 Jun  2 11:27 HelloWorld.xml");
if (m.find()) {
    String filename = m.group(1);   // HelloWorld.xml
}
```

Comment: I was doing group(1) instead of group(0)

Comment: Not sure how that worked for you because it doesn't for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a split instead :

```
public static void main( String args[] ) {
    String str = "drwxrwxr-x    2 bhannan  bhannan      4096 Jun  2 11:27 HelloWorld.xml";

    List list = Arrays.asList( str.split( "\\s+" ) );
    System.out.println( list.get( list.size() - 1 ) );
}
```

It outputs:

```
HelloWorld.xml
```